# Move Character to touched Position 2D (Without RigidBody and Animated Movement) UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, character

Good day. I am trying to achieve simple thing but nothing just works....

The desired output:

• Player touches a place in my world

• Character starting to smoothly move with walking animation towards that location

The actual result:

• Player touches a place in my world

• Character just jumps into the final point, no smooth movement nothing

Things tried:

```
• Vector2 finalPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position); 
transform.position = finalPosition;
```

In this scenario the character just jumps into the final point

```
• Vector2 finalPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position); 
transform.Translate(finalPosition);
```

In this case character just dissappears from the screen.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Vector2.Lerp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html) to move smoothly between two points.

Some pseudo code:

```
bool move;
float t;
Update()
{
    if () // insert condition to begin movement
    {
        move = true;
        t = 0; // reset timer
        startPos = transform.position; // store current position for lerp
        finalPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    if (move)
        MovePlayer();
}

void MovePlayer()
{
    t += Time.deltaTime / 3f; // 3 is seconds to take to move from start to end
    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, finalPosition, t);
    if (t > 3)
    {
        move = false; // exit function
    }
}
```

Comment: Just amazing! Worked like a charm, amazing answer with amazing explanational comments! PERFECT!

Answer (score 0):

in `update`:

```
transform.position += (final_pos - transform.position).normalized * Time.deltaTime;
```

this is adding to your current position the direction ... use delta time to scale the movement and you can increase or decrease the speed by multiplying it all by some scalar value, ie any `float` value. note that it’s best to `normalize` once rather than every frame but this is the general idea.

Comment: also note that the reason the character ‘disappears’ off the screen in your second example is because `Transform.translate` is essentially moving in the direction you’re giving it. basically doing what i did in my example. the issue is that you’re not scaling it by `deltaTime` so it happens so fast to seem immediate and you never tell it to stop so it goes on infinitely.